# Where in MS SQL Server 2008 R2 are list content

Tags: development, sql

Where in MS SQL Server 2008 R2 could I find out a content from all lists which I have got in my Site Colection. If I oppen MS SQL Serwer 2008 R2 I see a lot of data bases, but I don't know in which are the list content. Please help me.